# Выгрузка двумерного дерева (родитель-ребенок) из одной таблицы Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-8

Всем доброго дня.
Возник вопрос такого рода:
Как максимально правильно (хотелось бы в 1 запрос в БД) получить дерево родитель-ребенок из одной таблицы, где у ребенка в поле parent стоит id родителя, а у родителя NULL.
И вообще вер но ли строить такие деревья в одной таблице, или лучше разнести на несколько и делать выборку отношениями?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На выходе:

```
0 => [
   name => 'Имя 1'
   childs => [ 
      1 => [
           name => 'Имя ?'
      ],
      0 => [
           name => 'Имя ?'
      ]
   ]
]
```

**Благодарю всех кто откликнется!**

Comment: Правильно хранить в одной таблице. Если вам нужно строить дерево за раз, то выбираете все записи, а в php собираете древовидную структуру. Если записей очень много, то советую каждый узел асинхронно грузить через ajax (fetch)

Answer (score 1):

В Laravel правильным вариантом будет создать дерево через отношения. Не могу точно сказать, сколько запросов делает Laravel, но дерево Вы получите в точности как Вам надо.

Сама таблица у Вас сделана правильно (за исключением названия поля `parent_id`). Для получения дочерних элементов нужно в модели создать метод:

```
public function children() {
    return $this->hasMany(Self::class, 'parent_id')
                ->with('children');
}
```

Вызываете, соответственно, все значения верхнего уровня:

```
ModelName::whereParentId(null)->with('children')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Помнится, приходилось мне строить дерево для 2-х разных сущностей (марка-модель- модификация и узел1-узел2-...-узелN) Там суммарно тысяч 10 записей было в 4-х таблицах и таблица связей модификаций с узлами (многие ко многим) где-то около 1М записей. Так в рантайме полностью все дерево "за полиноминальное время" не строилось. Ни фреймворком (yii), ни чистыми php и SQL-запросами. Пришлось подгружать xhr по мере надобности.

Если же структура непересекающаяся и записей не слишком много, то в рантайме на чистом пхп я делаю обычно так:

- выбираю из бд все
- перебираю в цикле, создаю массив:

  ```
  [ parent_id => array( array(name, id), array(name, id), ...),
  parent_id => array( array(name, id), array(name, id), ...),
  ...
  parent_id => array( array(name, id), array(name, id), ...) ]
  ```
- потом, если не много уровней вложенности, рекурсивно строю часть DOM. Если много, но не очень, то в виде js массива или json на страницу и строить при помощи js итеративно сразу или по мере запроса.

В общем, реализация зависит от объема данных и от связей между этими данными.